# Given a finite palette, how to sort from Hot to Cold, i.e. Diverging

Tags: r, rgb, hsv, color-theory

**Update** (Original question below)

Issue is partially solved.

Still trying to figure out how to extend to other color combinations

If I use this code

```
hLIM <- rgb2hsv(col2rgb('#8000ff'))['h', ]
sLIM <- rgb2hsv(col2rgb('#8000ff'))['s', ]
vLIM <- rgb2hsv(col2rgb('#8000ff'))['v', ]
rankorder <- order((hLIM-tHSVcol[,1] + (hLIM < tHSVcol[,1])),
                   (sLIM-tHSVcol[,2] + (sLIM < tHSVcol[,2])),
                   (vLIM-tHSVcol[,3] + (vLIM < tHSVcol[,3])))

orderType <- "HSV Ordering"
```

I am able to sort this

[image]

**Unsorted Color Palette:**

`"#313695","#fdae61","#a50026","#ffffbf","#f46d43","#fee090","#e0f3f8","#74add1","#d73027","#4575b4","#abd9e9"`

Into this

[image]

**Sorted Color Palette:**

`"#a50026","#d73027","#f46d43","#fdae61","#fee090","#ffffbf","#e0f3f8","#abd9e9","#74add1", "#4575b4","#313695"`

However, I have difficulty extending it to other color combinations.

For Instance when I try to sort this

[image]

**Unsorted**

```
"#22325f" "#88ce64" "#fbd234" "#b8091f" "#682f4e" "#fdea6e" "#4aec6a" "#fb7894" "#f13111" "#2584a0" "#460809" "#00699e" "#391b72" "#03471d" "#ba0841"
```

I get this (Interesting part is, I'm unsure how the perfectly sorted palette would look like ---- certainly no dark bands interspersed!)

[image]

Imperfectly Sorted

```
"#391b72" "#22325f" "#00699e" "#2584a0" "#03471d" "#4aec6a" "#88ce64" "#fdea6e" "#fbd234" "#f13111" "#460809" "#b8091f" "#fb7894" "#ba0841" "#682f4e"
```

---

---

---

## Original Question

I have a finite palette, how to sort from Hot(reds) to Cold(blues).

How do I turn this

[image]

**Unsorted Color Palette:**

`"#313695","#fdae61","#a50026","#ffffbf","#f46d43","#fee090","#e0f3f8","#74add1","#d73027","#4575b4","#abd9e9"`

Into this

[image]

**Sorted Color Palette:**

`"#a50026","#d73027","#f46d43","#fdae61","#fee090","#ffffbf","#e0f3f8","#abd9e9","#74add1", "#4575b4","#313695"`

R Code is at the end of the message. I tried sorting by combinations of `RGB` and `HSV`, (based on what is commented, or uncommented) but to no avail.

I am unable to find a pattern in the following values (where colors are sorted divergently)

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

**RGB Sorted Color**

```
> tRGBcol
      red green blue
 [1,] 165     0   38
 [2,] 215    48   39
 [3,] 244   109   67
 [4,] 253   174   97
 [5,] 254   224  144
 [6,] 255   255  191
 [7,] 224   243  248
 [8,] 171   217  233
 [9,] 116   173  209
[10,]  69   117  180
[11,]  49    54  149
```

**HSV Sorted Color**

```
> tHSVcol
                h          s         v
 [1,] 0.961616162 1.00000000 0.6470588
 [2,] 0.008522727 0.81860465 0.8431373
 [3,] 0.039548023 0.72540984 0.9568627
 [4,] 0.082264957 0.61660079 0.9921569
 [5,] 0.121212121 0.43307087 0.9960784
 [6,] 0.166666667 0.25098039 1.0000000
 [7,] 0.534722222 0.09677419 0.9725490
 [8,] 0.543010753 0.26609442 0.9137255
 [9,] 0.564516129 0.44497608 0.8196078
[10,] 0.594594595 0.61666667 0.7058824
[11,] 0.658333333 0.67114094 0.5843137
```

Manually split hex colors

```
a5  00  26
d7  30  27
f4  6d  43
fd  ae  61
fe  e0  90
ff  ff  bf
e0  f3  f8
ab  d9  e9
74  ad  d1
45  75  b4
31  36  95
```

**Code**

```
RenderPal <- function(x,name){
  
  if ((missing(x)) || (missing(name))){
    stop("Internal error, please troubleshoot")
  }
  n <- length(x)
  old <- graphics::par(mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
  on.exit(graphics::par(old))
  
  graphics::image(1:n, 1, as.matrix(1:n), col = x,
                  ylab = "", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", bty = "n")
  graphics::rect(0, 0.9, n + 1, 1.1, col = grDevices::rgb(1, 1, 1, 0.8), border = NA)
  graphics::text((n + 1) / 2, 1, labels = name, cex = 2, family = "serif")
}

i <- NULL
oldPal <- NULL
rankorder <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
orderedPal<- NULL
RGBcol <- NULL
HSVcol <- NULL
tHSVcol <- NULL
orderType <- "Unsorted"



oldPal <- c("#313695","#fdae61","#a50026","#ffffbf","#f46d43","#fee090","#e0f3f8","#74add1","#d73027","#4575b4","#abd9e9")

# Print hex values
oldPal

# Convert Hex to RGB
RGBcol <- col2rgb(oldPal)

# Print RGB values
RGBcol

# Transpose matrix
tRGBcol <- t(RGBcol)

# Print matrix
tRGBcol

# Uncomment following to order by Red, Green, then Blue
# rankorder <- order(tRGBcol[,1],tRGBcol[,2],tRGBcol[,3])
# orderType <- "Red Ordering"

# Uncomment following to order by Blue, Green, then Red
# rankorder <- order(tRGBcol[,3],tRGBcol[,2],tRGBcol[,1])
# orderType <- "Blue Ordering"

# Uncomment following to order by Green, Blue then Red
# rankorder <- order(tRGBcol[,2],tRGBcol[,3],tRGBcol[,1])
# orderType <- "Green Ordering"

# Uncomment following to order by Red + Blue
# rANDb <- apply(tRGBcol[,c(1,3)],1,sum)
# rankorder <- order(rANDb)
# orderType <- "Red + Blue Ordering"

# Uncomment following to order by Red + Green + Blue
# rANDgANDb <- apply(tRGBcol[,c(1,2,3)],1,sum)
# rankorder <- order(rANDgANDb)
# orderType <- "Red + Green + Blue Ordering"

# Convert RGB to HSV
HSVcol <- rgb2hsv(RGBcol)

# Print matrix
HSVcol

# Transpose matrix
tHSVcol <- t(HSVcol)

# Print matrix
tHSVcol


# Uncomment following to order by Hue, then Saturation, then Value
# rankorder <- order(tHSVcol[,1],tHSVcol[,2],tHSVcol[,3])
# orderType <- "Hue Ordering"

# Uncomment following to order by hANDv = Hue + Value
# hANDv <- apply(tHSVcol[,c(1,3)],1,sum)
# rankorder <- order(hANDv)
# orderType <- "Hue + Value Ordering"

# Uncomment following to order by hPRODv = Hue * Value
# hPRODv <- apply(tHSVcol[,c(1,3)],1,prod)
# rankorder <- order(hPRODv)
# orderType <- "Hue * Value Ordering"

# Combine matrices tRGBcol and tHSVcol
tCombo <- cbind(tRGBcol,tHSVcol)

rankorder

for (i in 1:length(rankorder)){
  orderedPal[i] <- oldPal[rankorder[i]]
}

# Print old, unordered palette
oldPal

# Print new, ordered palette
orderedPal

RenderPal(oldPal, "Unordered Palette")
RenderPal(orderedPal, orderType)
```

Edit: Result when I sort by Hue

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174366/discussion-on-question-by-artie-ladie-given-a-finite-palette-how-to-sort-from-h).

Comment: 'HSV Ordering' example: I wonder if combining with a [grayscale formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615963/standard-rgb-to-grayscale-conversion) could be of any help here.

Comment: @Danny_ds I shall certainly try this out!

Answer (score 2):

I get almost your requested order with this:

```
Coolness = function(P) { 
    RGB = col2rgb(P)
    (RGB[3,] - RGB[1,]) / (RGB[3,] + RGB[1,])
}

CoolPal = oldPal[order(Coolness(oldPal))]
RenderPal(CoolPal, "Coolness")
```

[image: Palette Ordered by coolness]

But notice that I have swapped the first two colors. Your suggested answer says that 
"#a50026" is hotter than "#d73027". My Coolness function has the opposite ordering for those two.