# How to use R Machine Learning to Sort Colors

Tags: r, hsv, color-theory

Reference post, [Given a finite palette, how to sort from Hot to Cold, i.e. Diverging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158179/given-a-finite-palette-how-to-sort-from-hot-to-cold-i-e-diverging)

I am trying to grasp Machine Learning in R based on this tutorial, https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-r-step-by-step/. Unfortunately, I am unsure how to use this to approach sorting colors from Hot to Cold.

End of post has my code

I am trying to sort this

[image]

```
 [1] "#22325f" "#88ce64" "#fbd234" "#b8091f" "#682f4e" "#fdea6e" "#4aec6a" "#fb7894" "#f13111" "#2584a0"
[11] "#460809" "#00699e" "#391b72" "#03471d" "#ba0841"
```

Into this

[image]

```
 [1] "#391b72" "#22325f" "#03471d" "#00699e" "#2584a0" "#4aec6a" "#88ce64" "#fdea6e" "#fbd234" "#fb7894"
[11] "#f13111" "#b8091f" "#ba0841" "#682f4e" "#460809"
```

But instead, I get this (Random dark bands are especially troublesome).

HELP!!!

[image]

```
 [1] "#391b72" "#22325f" "#00699e" "#2584a0" "#03471d" "#4aec6a" "#88ce64" "#fdea6e" "#fbd234" "#f13111"
[11] "#460809" "#b8091f" "#fb7894" "#ba0841" "#682f4e"
```

CODE

```
RenderPal <- function(x,name){

  if ((missing(x)) || (missing(name))){
    stop("Internal error, please troubleshoot")
  }
  n <- length(x)
  old <- graphics::par(mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
  on.exit(graphics::par(old))

  graphics::image(1:n, 1, as.matrix(1:n), col = x,
                  ylab = "", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", bty = "n")
  graphics::rect(0, 0.9, n + 1, 1.1, col = grDevices::rgb(1, 1, 1, 0.8), border = NA)
  graphics::text((n + 1) / 2, 1, labels = name, cex = 2, family = "serif")
}

i <- NULL
oldPal <- NULL
rankorder <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
orderedPal<- NULL
RGBcol <- NULL
HSVcol <- NULL
tHSVcol <- NULL
orderType <- "Unsorted"



#oldPal <- c("#313695","#fdae61","#a50026","#ffffbf","#f46d43","#fee090","#e0f3f8","#74add1","#d73027","#4575b4","#abd9e9")

oldPal <- c("#22325f", "#88ce64", "#fbd234", "#b8091f", "#682f4e", "#fdea6e", "#4aec6a", "#fb7894", "#f13111", "#2584a0", "#460809", "#00699e", "#391b72", "#03471d", "#ba0841")


# Print hex values
oldPal

# Convert Hex to RGB
RGBcol <- col2rgb(oldPal)

# Print RGB values
RGBcol

# Transpose matrix
tRGBcol <- t(RGBcol)

# Print matrix
tRGBcol


# Convert RGB to HSV
HSVcol <- rgb2hsv(RGBcol)

# Print matrix
HSVcol

# Transpose matrix
tHSVcol <- t(HSVcol)

# Print matrix
tHSVcol



hLIM <- rgb2hsv(col2rgb('#8000ff'))['h', ]
sLIM <- rgb2hsv(col2rgb('#8000ff'))['s', ]
vLIM <- rgb2hsv(col2rgb('#8000ff'))['v', ]
rankorder <- order((hLIM-tHSVcol[,1] + (hLIM < tHSVcol[,1])),
                   (sLIM-tHSVcol[,2] + (sLIM < tHSVcol[,2])),
                   (vLIM-tHSVcol[,3] + (vLIM < tHSVcol[,3])))

orderType <- "HSV Ordering"

rankorder

for (i in 1:length(rankorder)){
  orderedPal[i] <- oldPal[rankorder[i]]
}

# Print old, unordered palette
oldPal

# Print new, ordered palette
orderedPal

RenderPal(oldPal, "Unordered Palette")
RenderPal(orderedPal, orderType)
```

Comment: Can't you just apply a formula for hot cold  and sort? Or what would you be learning from ?

Comment: Hello @Moody_Mudskipper I applied the formula, but it is quite limited. Entire thought process was in this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158179/given-a-finite-palette-how-to-sort-from-hot-to-cold-i-e-diverging. Someone mentioned this would be a Machine Learning project, but I am unsure how ....

Comment: A ML approach would work, however you need training and test data which you have not provided. You would need the "correct" colour format so that the ML algorithm can learn the correct format from all possible combinations of the colours you throw at it. What @Moody_Mudskipper suggested would work also very well.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper When I applied a forumula for hot cold and sort, I got undesired results, i.e. dark bands where there were supposed to be light colors, https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ8k8.jpg

Comment: Hot vs cold is not light vs dark, your result might be correct