# How to convert rgb to grayscale without using numpy scipy opencv or other imaging processing packages?

Tags: python

If the problem I am given is a nested tuple with rgb pixels, how do I convert that to grayscale and return a tuple with the grayscale pixel values. This should all be within one function.

Thanks

I honestly have no where to start since I am beginner programmer so would appreciate any help

Comment: Please add the code you're implementing here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming output entries are integers in range [0; 255] and your initial tuple named `image`:

```
from statistics import mean
gray_image = tuple(int(mean(pixel)) for pixel in image)
```

or more beginner friendly (and assuming pixels just default python integers, not uint8):

```
gray_image = []  # create empty list

for pixel in image:              
    R, G, B = pixel                # get rgb values
    gray_pixel = (R + G + B) // 3  # averaging to get gray
    gray_image.append(gray_pixel)

gray_image = tuple(gray_image) # turn list to tuple
```

It's simple averaging, but if there is need to get more technical, please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17619494/18635613).