# How does PyQt5's QGraphicsColorizeEffect() affect the color of a pixel exactly?

Tags: python, pyqt5, colorize, qgraphicseffect

I'm using **QGraphicsColorizeEffect()** in a python program to colorize a **QGraphicsPixmapItem**. I'm happy with how it works, as it's meant to highlight that the item has been "selected" by the user, however it made me wonder what is the exact logic or math behind the colorization process.

I understand that, when looking at the colors in the HSV color space, the colorization sets the **hue** of the target pixel to that of the tint color, but I'm not sure how it affects its **saturation** and its **value**.

So for example with a Base Color of (246, 134, 168) and a Tint of (120, 128, 128) the result is (120, 58, 176). How did we get here?

Here is a simple (I think) program that allow some experimenting with the QGraphicsColorizeEffect(). Every time it runs it prints to the console the Base color, Tint and Final color (in HSV).

Ideally I'd like a formula or the explanation of the algorithm so that I could predict what the final color would look like based on the Base color and the Tint that's going to be applied to it.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QBrush, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsColorizeEffect

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create a scene
scene = QGraphicsScene()

# Create a rectangle item with the specified size and color
rect = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 300, 150)
base_color = (246, 134, 168)
color = QColor.fromHsv(base_color[0], base_color[1], base_color[2])
rect.setBrush(QBrush(color))
rect.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
print(f"Base Color:     {base_color}")

# Add the rectangle to the scene
scene.addItem(rect)

# Create the effect
tint = (120, 128, 128)
effect = QGraphicsColorizeEffect()
effect.setColor(QColor.fromHsv(tint[0], tint[1], tint[2]))
print(f"Tint Color:     {tint}")

# Create a view and set the scene
view = QGraphicsView()
view.setScene(scene)

# Add the effect
rect.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

#Check color in the middle of the rectangle
pixmap = view.viewport().grab(QRect(QPoint(150, 75), QSize(1, 1)))
image = pixmap.toImage()
color = image.pixelColor(0, 0)
color = color.getHsv()
print(f"Final Color:    ({color[0]}, {color[1]}, {color[2]})")
        
# Show the view
view.show()
```

I've looked into the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QGraphicsEffect.html#more), but it doesn't seem to go in great detail on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is not documented as it's not considered to be important to the *normal* developer. The API is not fully exposed (as there's usually no need for that), and for the same reason, the implementation is written for optimization, rather than "dev usability".

Also, consider that most color transformations are done using the [RGB color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model): HSV, HSL, etc are alternate color models that are normally intended for different requirements.

The problem in finding how the colorize effect actually works is that it uses *lots* of internal functions and private classes; while you can use a smart code browser (like the one provided by [woboq](https://codebrowser.dev/)), some functions are created and accessed dynamically within the code, making their research quite difficult. You can usually easily access functions and definitions that are publicly available in the API (such as the basic implementation of a QGraphicsEffect), but finding out what they actually do is quite another story.

First of all, QGraphicsEffects classes must implement a [`draw()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html#draw) function, but graphics effects normally use advanced painting functions that are not part of the public API.
After some research, I can tell you how it works:

- QGraphicsColorizeEffect uses an [internal class](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/effects/qgraphicseffect_p.h?h=5.15#n177) (see it in the [woboq code browser](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/effects/qgraphicseffect_p.h.html#QGraphicsColorizeEffectPrivate)) that has a private [QPixmapColorizeFilter](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/effects/qpixmapfilter.cpp?h=5.15) ([woboq](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/effects/qpixmapfilter.cpp.html#1020));
- the graphics effect calls the `draw()` function of the filter;
- the filter creates a gray scale pixmap of the source;
- it sets the [`CompositionMode_Screen`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#CompositionMode-enum) on the painter for that pixmap (more on this later);
- fills the pixmap with the color of the effect, using the `strength()` as opacity for the painter, thus creating the "colorize" effect due to the composition mode;

Now, how can we do this on our own?

Considering your example, we can implement that with a single color, and we need two functions:

- transform the color into a gray scale;
- blend the gray with the new tint;

The first function is quite simple, there are various ways of doing it (see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17615963)), but Qt uses this simple formula:

```py
def toGray(r, g, b): # values are within the 0-255 range
    return (r * 11 + g * 16 + b * 5) / 32
```

Then the blending is done using the `CompositionMode_Screen`, which the documentation explains:

> The source and destination colors are inverted and then multiplied. Screening a color with white produces white, whereas screening a color with black leaves the color unchanged.

How it actually does that is a bit difficult to find, as compositions are helper function accessed "by attribute" (I believe); the `Screen` composition works [like this](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/painting/qcompositionfunctions.cpp?h=5.15#n1351) ([woboq](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/painting/qcompositionfunctions.cpp.html#_ZL21comp_func_Screen_implPjPKjiRKT_)):

```py
def blend(a, b):
    return 255 - ((255 - a) * (255 - b) >> 8)
#                  └invert  |  └invert
#                           └multiply

r1, g1, b1, _ = color1.getRgb()
r2, g2, b2, _ = color2.getRgb()
result = QColor(blend(r1, r2), blend(g1, g2), blend(b1, b2))
```

Considering the above, we can get more or less the correct result:

```py
def toGray(r, g, b):
    return (r * 11 + g * 16 + b * 5) / 32

def blend(a, b):
    return 255 - ((255 - a) * (255 - b) >> 8)

base_hsv = (246, 134, 168)
base_color = QColor.fromHsv(base_hsv[0], base_hsv[1], base_hsv[2])

tint = (120, 128, 128)
tint_color = QColor.fromHsv(tint[0], tint[1], tint[2])

gray = round(toGray(*base_color.getRgb()[:3]))
r, g, b, _ = tint_color.getRgb()
res_color = QColor(blend(gray, r), blend(gray, g), blend(gray, b))

# ...
color = image.pixelColor(0, 0)
print("Final Color:    ({}, {}, {})".format(*color.getHsv())
print("Computed Color: ({}, {}, {})".format(*res_color.getHsv())
```

The above, based on your colors, results in the following:

```py
Final Color:    (120, 58, 176)
Computed Color: (120, 59, 177)
```

Not perfect (probably due to rounding issues), but close enough.

But there's another issue: the effect also supports the [`strength`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicscolorizeeffect.html#strength-prop) property.

As said above, Qt does that by setting the opacity of the painter when drawing the source gray scale. But if we want to compute the color, that's not a valid solution: we want to compute the *final* color, not get its result after it's being painted.

In order to know the actual final result of the effect, we need to tweak the `blend()` function a bit, considering the original color:

```py
def blend(a, b, base, strength):
    value = 255 - ((255 - int(a)) * (255 - int(b)) >> 8)
    diff = value - base
    return base + diff * strength
```

The above will compute the blended component as done before, but then uses the difference between that and the source, and returns the sum of the source plus the difference multiplied by the strength ratio.

The result is still not perfect in integer values, but quite close to the result.

In order to clarify all the above, here is an example that show how it works, allowing color changes and strength factors, and finally comparing the resulting "colorized" value and the computed one:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def blend(a, b, base=None, strength=1.):
    value = 255 - ((255 - a) * (255 - b) >> 8)
    diff = value - base
    return (base or a) + diff * strength


class ColorButton(QPushButton):
    colorChanged = pyqtSignal(QColor)
    _color = QColor()
    def __init__(self, text, h, s, v):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.setColor(QColor.fromHsv(h, s, v))
        self.clicked.connect(self.changeColor)

    def changeColor(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor(self._color, self, self.text())
        if color.isValid():
            self.setColor(color)

    def color(self):
        return self._color

    def setColor(self, color):
        if self._color != color and color.isValid():
            self._color = QColor(color)
            pm = QPixmap(32, 32)
            pm.fill(color)
            self.setIcon(QIcon(pm))
            self.colorChanged.emit(QColor(color))


class ColorizeTest(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        tools = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(tools)
        self.srcButton = ColorButton('Source', 246, 134, 168)
        self.efxButton = ColorButton('Effect', 120, 128, 128)
        self.strengthSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, maximum=100)
        self.strengthSlider.setValue(100)

        tools.addWidget(self.srcButton)
        tools.addWidget(self.efxButton)
        tools.addWidget(self.strengthSlider)
        tools.addStretch()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()

        self.srcItem = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.efxItem = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100)
        self.compItem = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100)

        for i in self.srcItem, self.efxItem, self.compItem:
            i.setPen(QPen(Qt.NoPen))
            self.scene.addItem(i)

        self.efxItem.setX(self.srcItem.sceneBoundingRect().right())
        self.compItem.setX(self.efxItem.sceneBoundingRect().right())

        self.effect = QGraphicsColorizeEffect()
        self.efxItem.setGraphicsEffect(self.effect)

        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        labels = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(labels)
        self.srcLabel = QLabel()
        self.efxLabel = QLabel()
        self.compLabel = QLabel()
        for l in self.srcLabel, self.efxLabel, self.compLabel:
            labels.addWidget(l)
            l.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.srcButton.colorChanged.connect(self.updateColors)
        self.efxButton.colorChanged.connect(self.updateColors)
        self.strengthSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.updateColors)

    def updateColors(self):
        src = self.srcButton.color()
        tint = self.efxButton.color()
        strength = self.strengthSlider.value() * .01

        self.srcLabel.setText('{}, {}, {}'.format(*src.getHsv()))

        self.srcItem.setBrush(QBrush(src))
        self.efxItem.setBrush(QBrush(src))

        self.effect.setColor(tint)
        self.effect.setStrength(strength)

        center = self.view.mapFromScene(
            self.efxItem.sceneBoundingRect().center())
        pm = self.view.viewport().grab(QRect(center, QSize(1, 1)))
        pixelColor = pm.toImage().pixelColor(0, 0)
        self.efxLabel.setText('{}, {}, {}'.format(*pixelColor.getHsv()))

        sr, sg, sb, _ = src.getRgb()
        gray = round((sr * 11 + sg * 16 + sb * 5) / 32)
        er, eg, eb, _ = tint.getRgb()
        comp = QColor(
            blend(gray, er, sr, strength), 
            blend(gray, eg, sg, strength), 
            blend(gray, eb, sb, strength))
        self.compItem.setBrush(QBrush(comp))
        self.compLabel.setText('{}, {}, {}'.format(*comp.getHsv()))

    def showEvent(self, event):
        super().showEvent(event)
        self.updateColors()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: 
            self.view.fitInView(self.scene.itemsBoundingRect()))


app = QApplication([])

test = ColorizeTest()
test.show()
app.exec()
```

Finally, the above obviously doesn't consider the alpha channel of the source or the effect colors: the final resulting color can only depend on what the item is being painted on. Also, remember that the `grab` function can only consider the Qt context, if you're using transparency there is absolutely no way to know the exact result, unless you can access the OS capabilities: considering that, there's really no point in doing all this efforts, just grab a screenshot and get the pixel.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Just for reference or in case you want to edit it, the final example didn't run for me at first because the _blend_ function returned a float, while QColor (line 110) expected an int. I just used int() and now it seems to work as intended.  
Beside curiosity the reason I wanted to understand how this worked was that I thought it possible to get always the same _final color_ from any _base color_ by simply adapting the _tint color_ to it. This however doesn't appear to be possible as the minimum RGB values are always going to be the grayscale value.